# Get first row of a ascii file (headline) matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to get only the first row of a huge data file (about 80 columns and 16 000 rows). The first row is the row with the headlines (text). How do I get it?

Example:

```
idA idHI    idYesterday idWW2   idUK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way could be to use the function [fgetl](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) which, actually reads a file line by line.

- open the file in`read` mode with the function [fopen](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html)
- use `fgetl` to read the first line
- close the input file with the function [fclose](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fclose.html)

The read line is returned as a `string`

In case you want to get the single token of the string, you can use the functions:

- [textscan](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html)
- [strtok](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtok.html)

Read the first line

```
fp=fopen('huge_file.txt','r');
first_line=fgetl(fp)
fclose(fp);
```

Get the single tokens with `textscan`

```
tok_list=textscan(first_line,'%s')
```

Get the single tokens with `strtok`

**Edit**

*in case the delimiter is the `tab` character, it has to be specified as `char(9)` that is the ASCII code for `tab`.and not with the escape sequence `\t` as reported in the [strtok documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtok.html)*

*In the following example, the `char(9)` delimiter is used*

```
% [token,remain]=strtok(first_line,' ');
[token,remain]=strtok(first_line,char(9));

tok_list{1}=token
cnt=1;
while(1)
   if isempty(remain)
      break;
   end
   %[token,remain] = strtok(remain,' ');
   [token,remain] = strtok(remain,char(9));
   cnt=cnt+1;
   tok_list{cnt}=token
end
```

Given an input file such as

```
col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4
   16      2       3       13
    5     11      10        8
    9      7       6       12
    4     14      15        1
```

The output will be:

```
first_line =

col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4
```

Where `first_line` is `char` array

The single tokens are, using `textscan`:

```
tok_list = 

    {4x1 cell}

tok_list{1}

ans = 

    'col_1'
    'col_2'
    'col_3'
    'col_4'
```

or, using `strtok`

```
tok_list = 

    'col_1'    'col_2'    'col_3'    'col_4'
```

`tok_list` is a cellarray to allow having token of different size

Hope this helps,

Qapla'

Comment: Thanks, I however get this:
"Error using fgets
Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier."

Comment: The error seems clear: you have to first open the input file with the functin `fopen`. Check the first snippet of code in the answer: `fp=fopen('huge_file.txt','r');first_line=fgetl(fp);fclose(fp);`. Also, notice that I've used the function `fgetl` and not `fgets`.

Comment: I tried this:

fp=fopen('file','r');
first_line=fgetl(fp)
fclose(fp);
tok_list=textscan(first_line,'%s')
[token,remain]=strtok(first_line,' ');

tok_list{1}=token
cnt=1;
while(1)
   if isempty(remain)
      break;
   end
   [token,remain] = strtok(remain,' ');
   cnt=cnt+1;
   tok_list{cnt}=token
end
first_line

Comment: And does it work? Notice that the use of `textscan` and `strtok` are "alternative", you do not need to execute both, just select one.

Comment: It does not :( It gets stuck here: Error in fgetl (line 33)
[tline,lt] = fgets(fid);

Comment: Sorry! It works, I just missed to put in .txt : Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: The problem is just that the output matrix just puts all the headline into one mess as one word.

Comment: How are separate the labels in the headline? Can you post an example? Is the first line you want to read similar to the one I've used as example? `col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4`

Comment: I made an "example" above. The headlines consist of text of different length.

Comment: I've tested my code with your example and it works. I do not understand why your does not. Can you share the input file (e. g. Dorpobox)?

Comment: I cannot since it is under NDA, but I'll look in to it and will come back soon. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Here is an example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7534316/Test.txt

I have made it a bit shorter and removed the real data, but I think this shows what I want.

Comment: Sorry, at present I do not have access to MatLab. I'll be back on Saturday.

Comment: In your file, the token are separated by a `tab`. The split with `textscan` works. The use of `strtok` needs to be modified: in tha call the `tab` has to be defined as delimiter (second parameter in the call); the `tab` has to be specified as `char(9)` (and not as `\t`). I've also updated the example in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out tomorrow